# Is sending a status code while redirecting important?

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-301

The company I am working with has a main site with an `.com` tld, but also own multiple other tld's as `.de` and `.es`. These other tld's will always redirect using the underneath code. Should I add an `301 Moved Permanently` status code with the redirect or are these status code not important in this case? Or should a status code `204 No Content` be more suitable?

PHP Redirect code:

```
<?php
  header("Location: https://www.google.com");
  exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a permanent redirect, so you should use the 301 Moved Permanently status code. This link below explains the codes and why they are important:

> A 301 HTTP header is used when the requested URL permanently moved to a new location. As you are working on your site, you will often use this, because you regularly need to make a 301 redirect to direct an old URL to a new one. If you don’t, users will see a 404 error page if they try to open the old URL and that’s not something you want. Using a 301 will make sure that the link value of the old URL transfers to the new URL.

[HTTP Status Codes & SEO](https://yoast.com/http-status-codes/)